# Joining a string in another string

Tags: python, string

I have done this code but the output is not like what I want

```
def replace(s,p,n):
    return "".join("{}".format(p) if not i % n else char for i, char in enumerate(s,1))

print(replace("university","-",3))
```

the output that I get is `un-ve-si-y`

I must get it like :
`uni-ver-sit-y`

Comment: So you are replacing some characters in your string with `'-'`, but you want to be _inserting_ `'-'` into your string?

Comment: yes exactly, can you help me, please? @khelwood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one approach. using `str` slicing.

**Demo:**

```
def replace(s,p,n):
    return p.join([s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)])

print(replace("university","-",3))
```

**Output:**

```
uni-ver-sit-y
```

Answer (score 1):

If you extend the code out over multiple lines:

```
chars_to_join = []
for i, char in enumerate(s,1):
    if not i % n:
        chars_to_join.append("{}".format(p))
    else:
        chars_to_join.append(char)
```

You'll see that when the if statement is true it'll just replace the character rather than include the replacement character after the given character, so just modify the format string to include the currently iterated character aswell

```
"{}{}".format(char, p)
```

Comment: Couldn't `"{}{}".format(char, p)` just be `char + p` ?

Comment: @khelwood - Yes, I was trying not to change too many things in the OP's code

Answer (score 0):

For this question, I think the list-comprehension is not a very good idea. It's not clearly understood. Maybe we can make it clearer by following:

```
def replace(s,p,n):
    new_list = []
    for i, c in enumerate(s, 1):
        new_list.append(c)
        if i % n == 0:
            new_list.append(p)

    return "".join(new_list)


print(replace("university","-",3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do it functionally like this:

```
from itertools import repeat


def take(s, n):
    """"take n characters from s"""
    return s[:n]

def skip(s, n):
    """"skip n characters from s"""
    return s[n:]

def replace(s, p, n):

    # create intervals at which to prefix
    intervals = range(0, len(s), n)

    # create the prefix for all chunks
    prefix = map(skip, repeat(s), intervals)

    # trim prefix for n characters each
    chunks = map(take, prefix, repeat(n))

    return p.join(chunks)
```

And now:

```
replace('university', '-', 3)
```

Will give you:

```
'uni-ver-sit-y'
```

**Note:** this is sample code, if this is meant to be efficient you probably should use lazy evaluated functions (like `islice`) which can take a lot less memory for bigger inputs.